# jQuery mobile slider input change event

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery

I'm working with the jQuery mobile slider input. I can have multiple sliders in my page, and what happen it's that the "change" event it's fired very often, not just when the actual input value changes.
This is my code:

```
<div class="questionContent ui-hide-label" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="range" class="slider" value="" min="1" max="5" data-highlight="true" name="slider"  data-theme="b" />  
</div>

$('input.slider').each(function() {
    $(this)
    .bind('change',function() {
        console.log('changed')
    })
})
```

I also created a jsFiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/EAewE/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that jQuery in the background is changing the value of the input tied to the slider whenever the mouse is clicked, moved slightly etc. so the 'change' is actually triggering that often because it should be.

In jQuery Mobile you are better off using the [slidestop](http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/#event-stop) event which will only trigger when the slider stops moving. Note that this event is not fired when the input's value is changed programmatically, only when the actual slider is engaged by the user.